# How to prevent a floating box from moving when the box before it is hidden?

Tags: css-float

i have two boxes. both are floating to left. both the boxes have a function such that when a box is clicked, it hides. now the problem is that when box 1 is clicked, box 2 moves to take its place, that's the problem. i don't want the box 2 to move even a bit. Please help!
here's a demo or your understanding - http://jsfiddle.net/VdpJn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first box's onclick should read, `$(this).css("visibility", "hidden");`

Comment: Unfortunately, "display: none" removes the related element from the rendering process completely, which is not the case with "visibility: hidden" - the former retains the box used by the element but does not render its contents. You could easily write your own function to handle toggling using the "visibility" property in place of "display".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/joshuamartin/VdpJn/6/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="box" onclick="$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box" onclick="$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')" >Box 2</div>
    </body>
</html>​
```